# A property of the superdifferential

Tags: analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $u \in C(\Omega)$ and $\varphi \in C^1(\Omega)$.
Set, for $t \in (0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
u^t(x)=tu_1(x)+(1-t)\varphi(x).
\end{equation}
I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
D^+u^t(x)=\{q \in \mathbb{R}^n:q=tp+(1-t)D\varphi(x),p \in D^+u_1(x)\}.
\end{equation}
I use the following definition of superdifferential of $u$ in $\bar{x}$
\begin{equation}
D^+u(\bar{x})=\{p \in \mathbb{R}^n:u(x)\leq u(\bar{x})+p \cdot(x-\bar{x})+o(|x-\bar{x}|), \ x \rightarrow \bar{x} \}.
\end{equation}
I wrote the definitions of $D^+u^t(x)$ and $D^+u_1(x)$, then I tried to write the elements of the first set as a function of elements of the second, but from here I am not able to continue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start taking $q\in D^+u^t(\overline{x})$ and write the definition. Since $\varphi$ is $C^1$, you can use a Taylor expansion
$$\varphi(x)=\varphi(\overline{x})+\nabla\varphi(\overline{x})\cdot(x-\overline{x})+o(|x-\overline{x}|)$$
as $x\to\overline{x}$. Now rearrange terms leaving $u_1(x)$ alone on the left hand side of the inequality so that it looks like the definition of super differential of $u_1$, and you will see that 
$$\frac{q-(1-t)\nabla\varphi(\overline{x})}{t}\in D^+u_1(\overline{x})$$
is the $p$ you were looking for.